# How can I insert multiple rows into database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, insert

Here is my code:

```
$num = 5;
$voucher = new Voucher;

for ( $i = $num; $i > 0; $i-- ) {

    $token = generateRandomString(5, ['number', 'uppercase']);

    $voucher->prefix = $request->prefix;
    $voucher->token = $token;
    $voucher->description = $request->description;
    $voucher->date_time = time();
    $voucher->save();
}
```

Obviously my code should insert 5 rows. But surprisingly it inserts only 1 row. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `$voucher = new Voucher;` is in for loop!

Comment: @HirenGohel True .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are always using the same instance of the object. Each time you save the same row with different data. here is how to fix.

```
$num = 5;

for ( $i = $num; $i > 0; $i-- ) {

    $voucher = new Voucher;

    $token = generateRandomString(5, ['number', 'uppercase']);

    $voucher->prefix = $request->prefix;
    $voucher->token = $token;
    $voucher->description = $request->description;
    $voucher->date_time = time();
    $voucher->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new voucher within the for-loop. Currently, as you said, you are inserting the **same object** into the database five times

Answer (score 1):

You are using same instance everytime!
Create new one in every for loop like:

```
$num = 5;

for ( $i = $num; $i > 0; $i-- ) {

    $voucher = new Voucher;

    $token = generateRandomString(5, ['number', 'uppercase']);

    $voucher->prefix = $request->prefix;
    $voucher->token = $token;
    $voucher->description = $request->description;
    $voucher->date_time = time();
    $voucher->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic example create multi array and simply put in insert function.

```
$num = 5;
$dataArray = array();
for ( $i = $num; $i > 0; $i-- ) {

    $token = generateRandomString(5, ['number', 'uppercase']);

    $dataArray[$i]['prefix'] = $request->prefix;
    $dataArray[$i]['token'] = $token;
    $dataArray[$i]['description'] = $request->description;
    $dataArray[$i]['date_time'] = time();

}

Voucher::insert($dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a model instance, you may use the `fill` method to populate it with an array of attributes:

```
$num = 5;
$voucher = new Voucher;

for ( $i = $num; $i > 0; $i-- ) {

    $token = generateRandomString(5, ['number', 'uppercase']);

    $payload = [];
    $payload['prefix'] = $request->prefix;
    $payload['token'] = $token;
    $payload['description'] = $request->description;
    $payload['date_time'] = time();

    $voucher->fill($payload);
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment)